# Is there any way I can replace Ubuntu Budgie 20.04 (Dual Boot with Windows 10) with Focal Fossa without disturbing the data?

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, 20.04, budgie, reinstall

I have presently installed Ubuntu Budgie 20.04 as dual boot on my machine alongside W10. I want to replace Budgie with Focal Fossa without losing any of my data - any software(s), files etc.
Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: Did you try `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop` and then `sudo apt remove ubuntu-budgie-dekstop`?

Comment: Focal Fossa is the name of the developing version, that was released as 20.04 LTS. Do you mean to replace the Budgie Desktop with the standard Ubuntu Desktop? Or something else? Please explain.